# Creating picture gallery

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, web

I want to create a gallery of pictures for my website and upload those pictures from the administration panel of the website. I am going to show all pictures in a page with a very small size, and one place I will separate for each picture to show the selected picture (from small ones) with big size.

I know two ways of doing that:

1. I create 2 pictures for uploading from administration panel, one big and one small with a fixed size. So the big one I will load in the separate big space. And small will be shown in the small places. So the administrator of the site should CREATE 2 pics.
2. The second way I know is to use the GD library of PHP to be able to upload only the big picture, and in each place a PHP function will resize the big picture and get the 2 sizes that I need for the gallery.

The first method's disadvantage is, that the user of the site should use Photoshop or some other tool before uploading. Let’s agree that this is not a pleasant thing for the site user.

The second approach is not good either, as GD resizes the picture by lowering quality. And that loss is inadmissible because it is too much.

What is a way that does that resize operation while maintaining close to the original picture quality?

Or what is another approach that is better that these two?

Comment: You've put a bounty on this question but haven't commented on any of the answers here, what's wrong with them and what exactly do you need?

Comment: I want more variants of answers to be able to choose a better one for me, as I don't consider that these answers satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following function like this:

```
Image('/path/to/original.image', '1/1', '150*', './thumb.jpg'); // thumb, width = 150 px
Image('/path/to/original.image', null, '600*', './full.jpg'); // full, width = 600 px
```

You can specify the crop ratio via the second argument (w/h) if you wish, you can also specify the width and/or height of the resized image via the third argument (w*h).

```
function Image($source, $crop = null, $scale = null, $destination = null)
{
    $source = @ImageCreateFromString(@file_get_contents($source));

    if (is_resource($source) === true)
    {
        $size = array(ImageSX($source), ImageSY($source));

        if (isset($crop) === true)
        {
            $crop = array_filter(explode('/', $crop), 'is_numeric');

            if (count($crop) == 2)
            {
                $crop = array($size[0] / $size[1], $crop[0] / $crop[1]);

                if ($crop[0] > $crop[1])
                {
                    $size[0] = $size[1] * $crop[1];
                }

                else if ($crop[0] < $crop[1])
                {
                    $size[1] = $size[0] / $crop[1];
                }

                $crop = array(ImageSX($source) - $size[0], ImageSY($source) - $size[1]);
            }

            else
            {
                $crop = array(0, 0);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $crop = array(0, 0);
        }

        if (isset($scale) === true)
        {
            $scale = array_filter(explode('*', $scale), 'is_numeric');

            if (count($scale) >= 1)
            {
                if (empty($scale[0]) === true)
                {
                    $scale[0] = $scale[1] * $size[0] / $size[1];
                }

                else if (empty($scale[1]) === true)
                {
                    $scale[1] = $scale[0] * $size[1] / $size[0];
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $scale = array($size[0], $size[1]);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $scale = array($size[0], $size[1]);
        }

        $result = ImageCreateTrueColor($scale[0], $scale[1]);

        if (is_resource($result) === true)
        {
            ImageFill($result, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);
            ImageSaveAlpha($result, true);
            ImageAlphaBlending($result, true);

            if (ImageCopyResampled($result, $source, 0, 0, $crop[0] / 2, $crop[1] / 2, $scale[0], $scale[1], $size[0], $size[1]) === true)
            {
                ImageConvolution($result, array(array(-1, -1, -1), array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
                ImageJPEG($result, $destination, 90);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**The image is automatically enhanced (sharpened) and saved as a JPEG with high quality.**

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

GD doesn't lose quality any more than Photoshop. Just make sure you are using `imagecopyresampled()` and NOT `imagecopyresized()` as that does not do any kind of resampling. Then save the resulting image in high enough quality; for JPEG's, that's around 80.

Then do a similar resize in Photoshop and you'll see there's not much difference. You can also use GD to sharpen your thumbnails, that'll give them a little extra crispness.

**EDIT**

I made a tool to compare different resize methods, try it out and see for yourself what is the best method: http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/downsample/

Comment: I don't agree, that GD doesn't lose quality. Even Microsoft Picture Manager is processing pictures better than GD, even if I programm with imagecopyresampled() with 100% quality.

Comment: @Narek: I also don't think GD loses quality, what I've noticed is a slightly change in color variation. Either you stick to that or use ImageMagik (not sure if the image loses quality, but most people say not) or you just ask your uploaders to use Photoshop and upload 3 separate images. There is no golden solution here.

Comment: +, very nice showcase =) bigger pictures would be nice though, also this image is quite nice to see small differences http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Quality_comparison_jpg_vs_saveforweb.jpg

Comment: @Alix, the point was to show the differences (or lack of) between downsizing algorithms, that's the reason for small images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) instead of [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) to get probably better results. I'm not sure what level of integration with your website you need but I suggest checking the open source [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) project before you start coding.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [phpThumb()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)?

- You only need to generate src-links for your image tags.
- Automatic cache.
- Offers a lot of options to manipulate images. See the [demo](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php) page.
- Uses [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) and as fallback [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library), that you do not have to care about (but you can).
- Nearly everything can be configured. See: [phpThumb.config.php](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/index.php?source=phpThumb.config.php).

Comment: phpThumb is pretty good, you can also easily save a copy of the transformation in a cache so you don't have to do the resizing on each load

Answer (score 1):

How about using the quality argument of [`imagejpeg`](https://www.php.net/imagejpeg) when outputting your image?

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple shell script, which needs *convert* from ImageMagick:

```
#!/bin/sh

W=256
T="Some recent photos"

cat <<EOF
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>$T</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</HEAD>
<BODY STYLE="font-family: sans-serif">
<H1>$T</H1>
Click on the photos to enlarge<P>
EOF

for i
do
convert -resize $W "$i" "T$i"
cat <<EOF
<A HREF="$i"><IMG SRC="T$i" WIDTH=$W></A>
EOF
done

cat <<EOF
</BODY></HTML>
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use one file upload and then use ImageMagick to create the thumbnail on the server
(http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not picky about where the images are stored, you could use the Flickr PHP API. Since flickr provides the images in a variety of sizes, it leaves you with making the layout for the gallery.

Check out http://phpflickr.com/

I've used this for a project and was surprised at how easy it was. You can basically do every operation through that API, and you can do it for several users too, so you're going to save yourself and others lots of time. And not to mention space!-)